# Issue with C# inheritance when using Generics and 'new' modifier to hide a parent's member

Tags: c#, linq, generics, inheritance, modifier

I'm trying to create a class hierarchy with 2 levels
where the 2nd level overrides one of the properties (e.g. Id).

```
// Level 1
public class Level1 : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

// Level 2
public class Level2 : Level1
{
    // Override the 'Id' property in Level1
    // for the purpose of turning off auto-increment on Id.
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public new int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a self contained code snippet that demonstrates problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using Example;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Using concrete class, logic works correctly
        var tester = new Tester();

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        // Using Generic, result is incorrect
        var testerGeneric = new TesterGeneric<Level2>();
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Tester
{
    public Tester()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------ Tester Class ------");

        var listOfEntities = Level2.CreateDummyRecords();
        Console.WriteLine("List Count = " + listOfEntities.Count());        // Returns 6 (as expected)

        var groupedItems = listOfEntities.GroupBy(g => g.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Grouped By Count = " + groupedItems.Count());    // Returns 3 (as expected)
    }
}

public class TesterGeneric<TEntity>
                where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{
    public TesterGeneric()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------ TesterGeneric Class ------");

        var listOfEntities = (IEnumerable<TEntity>) Level2.CreateDummyRecords();
        Console.WriteLine("List Count = " + listOfEntities.Count());        // Returns 6 (as expected)

        var groupedItems = listOfEntities.GroupBy(g => g.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Grouped By Count = " + groupedItems.Count());    // Returns 1 (should be 3)
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace Example
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id {get; set;}
    }

    // Level 1
    public class Level1 : IEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    // Level 2
    public class Level2 : Level1
    {
        // Override the 'Id' property in Level1
        // for the purpose of turning off auto-increment on Id.
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public new int Id { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<Level2> CreateDummyRecords()
        {
            var theList = new List<Level2>();

            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=1 });

            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=2 });
            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=2 });

            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=3 });
            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=3 });
            theList.Add(new Level2() { Id=3 });

            return theList;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two "tester" classes

- **Tester**
- **TesterGeneric<TEntity>**

**Tester** uses the concrete class **Level2** and is correctly grouping the records by the **Id** property.

i.e. Output:

- 6 items in the list
- 3 groups of unique IDs

**TesterGeneric** reference Level2 through **TEntity** generic parameter
and is *incorrectly* grouping the records by the **Id** property.

i.e. Output:

- 6 items in the list
- 1 group only (and the group Key is 0)

**Question**:
How does this happen?

Comment: There are very very few times that shadowing a method or property or field with `new` is the way to go. It is evil and should be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we have very simple concept for new and override. Here you can understand then easily:

Whenever you override a child class property/method then if you cast child object into parent then you will have functionality of Child class.

Whenever you use new keyword with a child class property/method and then if you cast child object into parent then you will have parent class functionality.

Here is simple code example for you:

```
  class Parent
{
    public virtual int ID { get { return 40; } }

}

class ChildWithNew: Parent
{
    public new int ID { get { return 50; } }
}

class ChildWithOverride : Parent
{
    public override int ID { get { return 60; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("---Child with Override Kyword");
        ChildWithOverride cildWithOverride = new ChildWithOverride();

        Console.WriteLine(cildWithOverride.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(((Parent)cildWithOverride).ID);

        Console.WriteLine("---Child with New Kyword");
        ChildWithNew childWithNew = new ChildWithNew();

        Console.WriteLine(childWithNew.ID);
        Console.WriteLine(((Parent)childWithNew).ID);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @gaurav, it was very useful.

Problem solved. I now know the difference between Override and New.

Answer (score 2):

You are not overriding the property ID, Now you are only hiding your property. Once you provide virtual and override in ID the issue will be fixed.